# Does drawing a rectangle on the screen using RenderDrawRect take the same length of time as filling in every required pixel using RenderDrawPoint?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

Let's say I wanted to draw a *50px* by *60px* rectangle in SDL2 starting from the point (0,0). Is it faster to call `SDL_RenderDrawRect` `(renderer, SDL_Rect structure)` than to fill in every individual pixel using a nested for loop and calling `SDL_RenderDrawPoint`?

Or do both operations take the same length of time (which is what I think would happen)? I tried looking at the SDL source code, although I had difficulty fully understanding the functions for rendering.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that would be my absolute expectation.

Even if there was no hardware acceleration going on, there's more overhead in doing one function call per pixel. Think of just computing the address inside the surface where each pixel is going to be written: the pixel-at-a-time needs to compute that fresh every time, while the rectangle code must likely can re-use the last value it computed for the vast majority of writes. These things matter.

But there very likely *is* hardware acceleration, so the difference in performance can be great.

Always use the most high-level API function you can, to give more leverage for optimization and acceleration.

Comment: And this is without saying that reinventing the wheel (drawing a rectangle) is a total loss of time and will probably add a new bunch of bugs to your program. There is absolutely no benefit.

Comment: @xhienne No, reinventing the wheel would not add any bugs to any program, I know exactly how I'd go about it (it's actually quite simple, I briefly described it in my question). And there is benefit, because my reasoning behind this question was that I plan to create a program that fills non-rectangular shapes. As SDL does not have a direct function for this, I can either fill all rectangles within the said shape, or individually fill every pixel in the shape, which was the motivation behind the question.

Comment: @xhienne Regardless, there is absolutely nothing wrong with reinventing the wheel for practising, understanding and gaining experience.